# NPM is very slow on mac(maverik)

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, package

NPM is taking more than 10 min to install any small package like underscore.

`node -v 0.12.7`

`npm -v 2.11.3`

`IOS (maverik) 10.9.5`

I did a lot of research on google but couldn't find any solution.

Internet speed 10Mbps.

npm is also not generating any npm-debug.log file which i can share with you guys because its not failing to install a package.

What could be the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to clear NPM cache with `npm cache clean`? Sometimes could be useful when `npm install` is very slow.

Comment: I have just installed node/npm for the very first time in mac system. So i doubt that it will help.. but still i will try this...

Comment: I tried that.. no luck :(

Comment: Yes, on a fresh install is almost useless. Too bad. Do you have problems pinging or reaching `http://registry.npmjs.org`? If yes, you also can try to [set a mirror](http://registry.npmjs.org).

Comment: Ping request could not find host http://registry.npmjs.org/. Please check the name and try again. but the site opens in browser.

Comment: You're not behind any proxy (or have any specific proxy-like config in your `bash_profile`?)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get the problem but even i faced the similar issue long back. By disabling the `npm install progress bar` during downloads, you can significantly cut down on download times.

`npm set progress=false`

And also check that you are behind the proxy or not!!! sometimes acessing behind proxy might slow down things.